# Combining Sencha Touch 2.1 with Java

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

Is there a way to combine a Sencha Touch 2.1 solution with pure Java code instead of Javascript only? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Use Sencha Touch in a container that supports native extensions, such as PhoneGap, or
- Roll your own container using a `WebView` that renders your Sencha Touch UI, where you provide access to native Java objects via `WebView`'s `addJavaScriptInterface()` method, so your JavaScript can call methods on the Java objects